# Core Data loading in background problem

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have setup few methods to load core data in the background using NSOperationQueue, like the below:

```
operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self                                                      
selector:@selector(selectToLoadDataOne) object:nil];

operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self                                                      
selector:@selector(selectToLoadDataTwo) object:nil];
```

The "selectToLoadDataOne" and "selectToLoadDataTwo" is just standard NSFetchRequest using the template NSManagedContext from app delegate.
Problem is that after loading a few times, it just stop loading altogether and stuck at executeFetchRequest: and without any error.

I know this is related to using of threads with core data, and so I tried to create a new nsmanagedobjectcontext for each call but the result returned are empty nsmanagedobject.

Can someone point me to a good example or doc I can use to solve the loading of core data from background thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data has **very** specific rules about running on multiple threads.  You must have one `NSManagedObjectContext` per thread and the thread that a `NSManagedObjectContext` will be used on must be the thread that creates it.

You are running into issues because you are breaking that rule.

Instead of using a `NSInvocationOperation`:

1. create a subclass of `NSOperation`
2. pass in the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`
3. create the `NSManagedObjectContext` in the -main

Of course that is only going to load them into the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and you are still going to need to reload them in the main `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Why do you need to load data on a background thread?  Looking to speed up data loads is usually indicative of a deeper issue in the app.

Comment: Lack of experience and the need to display the spinning wheel while the data is loading. :-)

Comment: Loading data from sqlite should be very fast. If it is not then I suggest you look at that problem. Loading it on a background thread won't solve your problem at least not without a lot of pain. Optimize the data load; debug the sql, see why it is slow and fix the core issue.